# PLL with two input frequency within lock range for FM demodulation

Tags: pll, demodulation

I have current output from a photodiode which I believe containing at least two distinct frequencies that is not too far apart from the lock range of a PLL which taking this current as the input frequency.

I have seen this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195010/how-do-i-differentiate-two-distinct-frequencies-24mhz-and-40mhz), but it is not asking what I am asking.

The question what the PLL is expected to do with these situation (in theory).

Empirically, I observe that the output signal is switching between two states of the frequencies. I wonder if this is agreeable to the theory.

Note: possibly circuit may look like this
[image]

Update:
I found a close question asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72387/whats-the-principle-of-a-pll-used-as-demodulator-of-a-fm-signal?rq=1)

Comment: there is no such thing as 'a PLL', they come in many different implementations. How they behave to 'unusual' inputs will be determined by (a) what the signal conditioning is at the input and (b) what type of phase detector is used. Put a schematic of the PLL, at least the input to PSD part of it, into your OP.

Comment: A "mixer", as in the doubly-balanced mixer, gives different behavior than does a standard PFD. And with two tones, with the standard PFD needing rail-rail LOGIC inputs, the "two tones" must become limited or clipped. Whereas the doubly-balanced mixer may function quite well with two-summed-tones as input.